# (Python/Pygame) Best way to load a LOT of images at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a function to load sounds, but not one for loading images. This is how my image loading is layed out currently:

```
if os.path.exists("themes/voltorb"):
    vgui = pygame.image.load("themes/voltorb/gui.png")
    voptions = pygame.image.load("themes/voltorb/options.png")
    vachievements = pygame.image.load("themes/voltorb/achievements.png")
    voverlay = pygame.image.load("themes/voltorb/overlay.png")
    vconfirm = pygame.image.load("themes/voltorb/confirm.png")
    vboom = pygame.mixer.Sound("themes/voltorb/boom.mp3")
    vcoin = pygame.mixer.Sound("themes/voltorb/coin.mp3")
    vtheme = {"gui":vgui,"options":voptions,"achievements":vachievements,"overlay":voverlay,"confirm":vconfirm,"coin":vcoin,"boom":vboom,"music":vmusic}
    themedb.update({"v":vtheme})
if os.path.exists("themes/fluttershy"):
    fcoin = pygame.mixer.Sound("themes/fluttershy/coin.mp3")
    fgui = pygame.image.load("themes/fluttershy/gui.png")
    foptions = pygame.image.load("themes/fluttershy/options.png")
    fachievements = pygame.image.load("themes/fluttershy/achievements.png")
    foverlay = pygame.image.load("themes/fluttershy/overlay.png")
    ftheme = {"gui":fgui,"options":foptions,"achievements":fachievements,"overlay":foverlay,"confirm":fconfirm,"coin":vcoin,"boom":vboom,"music":vmusic}
    themedb.update({"f":ftheme})
if os.path.exists("themes/mario"):
    mgui = pygame.image.load("themes/mario/gui.png")
    moptions = pygame.image.load("themes/mario/options.png")
    machievements = pygame.image.load("themes/mario/achievements.png")
    moverlay = pygame.image.load("themes/mario/overlay.png")
    mtheme = {"gui":mgui,"options":moptions,"achievements":machievements,"overlay":moverlay,"confirm":mconfirm,"coin":vcoin,"boom":vboom,"music":vmusic}
    themedb.update({"m":mtheme})
if os.path.exists("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret1"):
    s1gui = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret1/gui.png")
    s1options = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret1/options.png")
    s1achievements = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret1/achievements.png")
    s1overlay = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret1/overlay.png")
    s1theme = {"gui":s1gui,"options":s1options,"achievements":s1achievements,"overlay":s1overlay,"confirm":s1confirm,"coin":vcoin,"boom":vboom,"music":vmusic}
    themedb.update({"s1":s1theme})
if os.path.exists("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret2"):
    s2gui = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret2/gui.png")
    s2options = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret2/options.png")
    s2achievements = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret2/achievements.png")
    s2overlay = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret2/overlay.png")
    s2theme = {"gui":s2gui,"options":s2options,"achievements":s2achievements,"overlay":s2overlay,"confirm":s2confirm,"coin":s2coin,"boom":s2boom,"music":s2music}
    themedb.update({"s2":s2theme})
if os.path.exists("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret3"):
    s3gui = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret3/gui.png")
    s3options = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret3/options.png")
    s3achievements = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret3/achievements.png")
    s3overlay = pygame.image.load("%appdata%/KWScripts/Voltorb/themes/secret3/overlay.png")
    s3theme = {"gui":s3gui,"options":s3options,"achievements":s3achievements,"overlay":s3overlay,"confirm":s3confirm,"coin":s3coin,"boom":s3boom,"music":s3music}
    themedb.update({"s3":s3theme})
```

I'm not sure if there's any easy way to do this, but I have the most difficult way typed already. If anyone has an idea of how to shorten this, then thanks!

Comment: why not store the images and their file descriptors in a dict? `{'vgui': 'themes/voltorb/gui.png', etc. }` Then, you can just iterate through it once and you're done.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Could you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take all your images and put them in a dict, where the key is the variable you were using, and the value is the path:

```
vimages = {'vgui': "themes/voltorb/gui.png", 'voptions': "themes/voltorb/options.png", 'vachievements': "themes/voltorb/achievements.png"} # and so on...
```

Then, iterate through `vimages`, checking for the existence of each individual file, then calling `pygame.image.load()` on it, and store the result in your already-existing dict (`vtheme`, in this case).

This way, you don't need to keep writing out `pygame.image.load()` over and over again.

Comment: So: vtheme = pygame.image.load(vimages) ?